# How to get a nested Gutenberg block to parse

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I'm looking for way to get a specific Gutenbergblock from my post content to use in the archive template. Somewhere in my single post there's an iconlist (nested in a column and the column nested in a row) that I would like to use as a summary of the page in the entry on the archive page.
I wrote this code to search for the block called 'kadence/iconlist' and render it.

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID();
$post = get_post($post_id);
$blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);
foreach ($blocks as $block) { 
    if ($block['blockName'] == 'kadence/iconlist') {
        echo render_block($block);
    }
} ?>
```

This renders nothing because the 'kadence/iconlist' is nested. A var_dump of the $block shows this structure:

```
Array
(
    [blockName] => kadence/rowlayout
    [attrs] => Array
        (
            [uniqueID] => _94b9e4-63
            [columnGutter] => wider
            [colLayout] => equal
            [maxWidth] => 1220
            [topPadding] => 55
            [bottomPadding] => 55
            [overlayFirstOpacity] => 1
            [overlaySecondOpacity] => 1
            [overlayOpacity] => 90
            [align] => full
            [firstColumnWidth] => 50
            [secondColumnWidth] => 50
        )

    [innerBlocks] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [blockName] => kadence/column
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [topPadding] => 25
                            [bottomPadding] => 25
                            [leftPadding] => 25
                            [rightPadding] => 25
                            [uniqueID] => _91ffee-25
                        )

                    [innerBlocks] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [blockName] => kadence/advancedgallery
                                    [attrs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [uniqueID] => _ccc1ba-38
                                            [columns] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 2
                                                    [1] => 2
                                                    [2] => 2
                                                    [3] => 2
                                                    [4] => 1
                                                    [5] => 1
                                                )

                                            [thumbSize] => full
                                            [ids] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 355
                                                    [1] => 354
                                                    [2] => 357
                                                    [3] => 353
                                                    [4] => 351
                                                    [5] => 352
                                                    [6] => 349
                                                    [7] => 348
                                                    [8] => 350
                                                )

                                            [type] => thumbslider
                                            [imageRatio] => square
                                            [linkTo] => media
                                            [gutter] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 40
                                                    [1] => 
                                                    [2] => 
                                                )

                                            [imageRadius] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 0
                                                    [1] => 0
                                                    [2] => 0
                                                    [3] => 0
                                                )

                                            [autoPlay] => 1
                                            [autoSpeed] => 4000
                                            [lightbox] => magnific
                                            [margin] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [desk] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0
                                                                    [1] => 0
                                                                    [2] => 0
                                                                    [3] => 0
                                                                )

                                                            [tablet] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 
                                                                    [1] => 
                                                                    [2] => 
                                                                    [3] => 
                                                                )

                                                            [mobile] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 
                                                                    [1] => 
                                                                    [2] => 
                                                                    [3] => 
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [thumbnailRatio] => square
                                            [thumbnailColumns] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 4
                                                    [1] => 4
                                                    [2] => 4
                                                    [3] => 4
                                                    [4] => 4
                                                    [5] => 4
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [innerBlocks] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [innerHTML] => 
Previous









Next
Previous






















Next


                                    [innerContent] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
Previous









Next











                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [innerHTML] => 


                    [innerContent] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 

                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 


                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [blockName] => kadence/column
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [uniqueID] => _b56b72-c0
                        )

                    [innerBlocks] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [blockName] => kadence/advancedheading
                                    [attrs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [level] => 1
                                            [uniqueID] => _1f94db-5b
                                        )

                                    [innerBlocks] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [innerHTML] => 
RVS-200HD+


                                    [innerContent] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
RVS-200HD+


                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [blockName] => kadence/iconlist
                                    [attrs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [items] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [icon] => fe_check
                                                            [link] => 
                                                            [target] => _self
                                                            [size] => 20
                                                            [text] => Voordeel nummer 1 iets met emmers
                                                            [width] => 2
                                                            [color] => 
                                                            [background] => 
                                                            [border] => 
                                                            [borderRadius] => 0
                                                            [borderWidth] => 1
                                                            [padding] => 5
                                                            [style] => default
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [icon] => fe_check
                                                            [link] => 
                                                            [target] => _self
                                                            [size] => 20
                                                            [text] => Puntje 2
                                                            [width] => 2
                                                            [color] => 
                                                            [background] => 
                                                            [border] => 
                                                            [borderRadius] => 0
                                                            [borderWidth] => 1
                                                            [padding] => 5
                                                            [style] => default
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [icon] => fe_check
                                                            [link] => 
                                                            [target] => _self
                                                            [size] => 20
                                                            [text] => Puntje 3, deze zijn per bericht gewoon aan te passen 
                                                            [width] => 2
                                                            [color] => 
                                                            [background] => 
                                                            [border] => 
                                                            [borderRadius] => 0
                                                            [borderWidth] => 1
                                                            [padding] => 5
                                                            [style] => default
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [icon] => fe_check
                                                            [link] => 
                                                            [target] => _self
                                                            [size] => 20
                                                            [width] => 2
                                                            [color] => 
                                                            [background] => 
                                                            [border] => 
                                                            [borderRadius] => 0
                                                            [borderWidth] => 1
                                                            [padding] => 5
                                                            [style] => default
                                                            [text] => En toe te voegen
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [listCount] => 4
                                            [uniqueID] => _342687-70
                                        )

                                    [innerBlocks] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [innerHTML] => 
Voordeel nummer 1 iets met emmers
Puntje 2
Puntje 3, deze zijn per bericht gewoon aan te passen 
En toe te voegen


                                    [innerContent] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
Voordeel nummer 1 iets met emmers
Puntje 2
Puntje 3, deze zijn per bericht gewoon aan te passen 
En toe te voegen


                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [blockName] => core/block
                                    [attrs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ref] => 918
                                        )

                                    [innerBlocks] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [innerHTML] => 
                                    [innerContent] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [innerHTML] => 






                    [innerContent] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 

                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 


                            [3] => 
                            [4] => 


                            [5] => 
                            [6] => 


                        )

                )

        )

    [innerHTML] => 


    [innerContent] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

            [1] => 
            [2] => 


            [3] => 
            [4] => 


        )

)
Array
(
    [blockName] => 
    [attrs] => Array
        (
        )

    [innerBlocks] => Array
        (
        )

    [innerHTML] => 


    [innerContent] => Array
        (
            [0] => 


        )

)
```

How do I have to change the if($block['blockName'] == 'kadence/iconlist' to actually get to the kadence/iconlist block?